# UINavigationController crashes after pushing 3 views onto stack

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation controller, which has the following structure:

```
Category
    Item
        Item Detail
```

I can choose a category, and then choose an item to see its details. I can do this twice, i.e. go `Back` to the list of items and select another item. If i try this a third time, the app crashes, I get `objc_msgSend` in stack but thats all. But, instead of choosing another item, i go to the list of categories, and choose a different category, I can select two items in that category, before it crashes also.

What would be causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I was overreleasing a variable. Used Allocations in Instruments with the record reference counts and nszombie options switched on to track it down.

Answer (score 0):

It may due to the way you declare private variable. The answer is embedded in my question posting here:
[UINavigationController crash because of pushing and poping UIViewControllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807301/uinavigationcontroller-crash-because-of-pushing-and-poping-uiviewcontrollers)